# Rails route without controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, minitest

In my routes file, I have this random route without a controller

```
match "/ping" => lambda{ |env| [200, {'Content-Type' => 'text/plain'}, ['ACK']] }
```

Using Test::Unit / MiniTest, how would I go about testing, that yes the route /ping return 'ACK'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a route without a controller, you cannot use `ActionController::TestCase` to test it. Instead, you should use `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest`. Create a file at `test/integration/ping_test.rb` that includes the following:

```
require "test_helper"

class PingTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  def test_ping
    get "/ping"
    assert_response :success
    assert_equal "ACK", response.body
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Definitely using integration tests. See details here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#integration-testing